# Concurrent update of bit-fields in C

Tags: c

Section 3.15.3 of the C standard states:

> "it is not safe to concurrently update two non-atomic bit-fields in
>   the same structure if all members declared between them are also
>   non-zero-length bit-fields, no matter what the size of those
>   intervening bit-fields happen to be."

Consider the below example:

```
struct S {
  unsigned a: 8;
  unsigned b: 4;
  unsigned c: 4;
  unsigned d: 8;
};
```

Based on the standard, it's not safe to update bit-fields `a` and `d` concurrently.

Why not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bit fields aren't individually addressable, so to set a bit field, the compiler makes machine code to:

1. Read the byte that includes the bits to set
2. Set the required bits in that byte
3. Write the whole byte back.

Sometimes this is done in a single instruction, but then the processor does the same job.

Either way, if another thread is simultaneously doing he same sort of thing on other bits in the same byte, then the operations of the two threads can interfere with each other.

Note also:  you can't rely on the unit of access being a byte, it could be a whole `int` or `unsigned`, for example.

Comment: I know bit fields are not individually addressable. But I don't understand why the standard says "no matter what the size". If the sizes of bit-fields b and c above are, let's say 64 and 64 (making stuff up here), the standard says its not safe to concurrently update a and d (which are separated by more than 16 bytes). So, it doesn't specifically answer the question.

Comment: Well, there might be or come a time when processors are using words with more than 128 bits. Just because our common CPUs have 64 bit width and most people think it's more than enough this doesn't have to be carved in stone. I think the standard didn't want to set a limit.

Comment: @user3124390  It says "no matter what size", because the alternative is to provide guarantees of separation with certain patterns of sizes.  That would be complicated and would imply implementation choices that the standard didn't want to make. Instead they gave you explicit mechanism for separating them -- the 0-size bit field.

Comment: that makes sense.